# Show UIImageView on screen Tap

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I am trying to Display a an Image when the user Taps on the `UIImageView`. But before the user Taps the `UIImageView` the Image should not be shown, and after a few seconds the Image should disappear again. Does anyone know how to do this? I read through couple of Threads but they do not work with the latest Xcode as it appears. Thanks for your help and time.

*Udate*

Well, my code now looks like this:

```
    -(void)imageTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
    {
        recognizer.view.alpha=0.0;
        ((UIImageView*)recognizer.view).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"twingo_main.png"];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:2.0 options:0 animations:^{
            recognizer.view.alpha=1.0;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            recognizer.view.alpha=0.0;
            ((UIImageView*)recognizer.view).image = nil;
            recognizer.view.alpha=1.0;
        }];
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {

        UIImageView *hiddenImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 30, 20, 20)];
        hiddenImage.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
        [hiddenImage addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped:)]];
        [self.view addSubview:hiddenImage];
```

Well, now my question is, how do I need to set up the UIImageView in the View Controller?

Comment: What have you tried? What does your code look like now? A hint would be to modify the `alpha` property of the `UIImageView`. This property is animatable.

Comment: user TapGesture on UIimageView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `UIViewController`'s viewDidLoad method:

```
    ...

UIImageView *hiddenImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 30, 20, 20)];
        hiddenImage.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
        [hiddenImage addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped:)]];
        [self.view addSubview:hiddenImage];
    ...
```

UITapGestureRecognizer Handler:

```
-(void)imageTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{
    recognizer.view.alpha=0.0;
    ((UIImageView*)recognizer.view).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:2.0 options:0 animations:^{
        recognizer.view.alpha=1.0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        recognizer.view.alpha=0.0;
        ((UIImageView*)recognizer.view).image = nil;
        recognizer.view.alpha=1.0;
    }];
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you. After implementing the code, how do I have to link it with the Image?

Comment: @Niclas please see the edit.  You can simply put the top code anywhere in your viewController's viewDidLoad method.

Answer (score 0):

Set the image in the `UIImageView` to nil initially. Add a tap gesture recognizer to the `UIImageView` that, when fired, sets the image and starts a timer. When the timer completes, set your image back to nil.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an another way to handle above with NSTimer..

```
    -(void)imageTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
    {    

        CustomPopUpView *lCustomPopUpView = [[CustomPopUpView alloc]init];
        //Added your imageview to Custom UIView class
        [self.window addSubview:lCustomPopUpView];
        [self.window bringSubviewToFront:lCustomPopUpView];
        mPopupTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self  selector:@selector(closePopUp) userInfo:Nil repeats:FALSE]; 

     }
    - (void)closePopUp{             

        if (mPopupTimer != nil) {
            [mPopupTimer invalidate];
            mPopupTimer = nil;
        }
        for (UIView *lView  in self.window.subviews) {
            if ([lView isKindOfClass:[CustomPopUpView class]]) {
                [lView removeFromSuperview];
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better to have view behind the `UIImageView` to handle the `TapGesture`.
But here is the fix for you code:

Add this to `viewDidLoad`  method to setup you image view to handle tap gesture

```
//By default the UserInteraction is disabled in UIImageView
       [self.testImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapgesture=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(ShowImage:)];
        tapgesture.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
        tapgesture.numberOfTouchesRequired=1;

        [self.testImageView addGestureRecognizer:tapgesture];
```

here is the method handle the gesture event

```
-(void)ShowImage:(UIGestureRecognizer*)recognizer{

    recognizer.view.alpha=0.0;
    ((UIImageView*)recognizer.view).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"clone.jpg"];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
        recognizer.view.alpha=1.0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        //[self performSelector:@selector(hideImage:) withObject:recognizer.view afterDelay:10];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:3.0 options:0 animations:^{
            recognizer.view.alpha=0.0;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            ((UIImageView*)recognizer.view).image=nil;
            ((UIImageView*)recognizer.view).alpha=1.0;
        }];
    }];

}
```

If you set the alpha of view to 0, then your view will not receive any touch event further. So its best practice to set it again to 1.0 after removed the image from `UIImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using a `UIButton`. Detecting touches with these is easy - as is changing their image.

You could also subclass `UIControl` (see http://www.raywenderlich.com/36288/how-to-make-a-custom-control).